# Is there a way to free up a thread blocked on a socket without closing the socket?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have a thread that is constantly blocking on a socket, reading in everything, then blocking again, waiting for more. It's part of an asynchronous communication protocol responsible for getting responses and handing them out to the various threads/windows that made the requests. It also handles responding to "still alive?," time out messages, etc etc. What I'm looking for is a way to shut down this loop with a method call, basically to free up the socket for some manual intervention, in case I ever need it.

The way I was once told to unblock a thread that's waiting on a socket is to have something else call Close on the socket, though I don't want to do that, I'd rather keep it open. Kludgier ways I've handled this in the past was to either turn off blocking on the socket, and just have it sleep for intervals, or set a socket timeout to keep looping through, but both of those are a form of polling, something I want to avoid.

Perhaps there's some way I could do it using events, is there an event thrown when the socket has some data for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Thread.Interrupt - the blocking call will return with an ThreadInterruptedException which needs to be handled.

You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx)

Comment: That might work well, as long as I make sure to handle it right so that I don't kill it while blocking at something else. And Catch a ThreadInterrupedException from around the socket reading. And no where near as dangerous seeming as Thread.Abort. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, asynchronous I/O programming is among the hardest things to do correctly (in any language). In Windows, the typical approach is to use something called [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Fortunately, in .NET this is somewhat simplified by the Socket class which supports async eventing as a way to notify you that a pending operation has completed on a socket. The [MSDN documentation for AsyncSocketEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) has a decent example.

For more info, take a look at [C# Sockets Async Events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod) on CodeProject.com.

Comment: Oh dear that thing is massive. Thanks though!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately IO completion is not for the faint for heart, but it's one of the limited set of ways to reliably perform asynchronous communications.

Comment: It also doesn't help that I'm trying to do something wonky with it. In theory this loop should always be the one with access to the socket, but not I'm adding it as an internal feature to a library of mine (code reuse and all that), but once I turn on that feature, I can't turn it off. So I wanted a way to basically take the socket back. It looks like I can do what I want with the suggested Thread.Interrupt though

Comment: I meant now, as in, now I'm adding it to a library. Not not

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the socket open, why do you want to interrupt the thread waiting on it for data?  If this thread can do other stuff as well as waiting on his socket, you can:

1) Use overlapped I/O using either the 'hEvent' wait-handle+WaitForMultipleObjects, a completion routine or full IOCP.

2) Move all the not-blocking-on-socket activity to another thread that waits with WFMO on a handle array, one of which is communicating from the thread that is only doing the blocking reads.

If you really must unblock the one thread waiting on a blocking call without closing it, you could maybe arrange to have it sent some data.  Send an echo request on the socket to the peer client/server.  It will then reply, unblocking the rx thread waiting on it.